# Active Dives should be Active when Refreshing the page

Tags: php

I have page with dives, some of them have display none property, i can enable them by clicking button of top, But when i submit page or refresh page, the active dives disables, 
I want to remain them enable how?

E.g: Normal No show drop downs.
Click of button for activating div. and drop down shows, when submit form the same form appears with default view, i want to the recent active drop down after refreshing the page.. How???

i have tried everything but nothing happens....

```
<form> 
    <div id="cntblock2" style="padding-bottom:6px; display:none;"> 
        <strong>Origem:</strong><br /> 
        {$formdata.selectcountriesfrom}
    </div> 
    <input class="button" name="btngetquote" id="btngetquote" value="" type="submit" style="float:left; background:url({$base_dir}/modules/parcelmix/btn_VER_PRECOS.png) no-repeat; border:0px; height:30px; width:117px;"" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: <form>
    <div id="cntblock2" style="padding-bottom:6px; display:none;">
        <strong>Origem:</strong><br />
       {$formdata.selectcountriesfrom}</div>

       <input class="button" name="btngetquote" id="btngetquote" value="" type="submit" style="float:left; background:url({$base_dir}/modules/parcelmix/btn_VER_PRECOS.png) no-repeat; border:0px; height:30px; width:117px;"" />
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>

Comment: Please post your attempted solutions. I assume you were using cookies.

Answer (score 0):

as possible your manipulation element enabled and disabled via jquery.

**.prop( propertyName )**

```
Description: Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements.
```

you can see in this article http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thanks, this is how i control active dives...
{if $formdata.country==1}
  {literal}
        <script type="text/javascript">
        showcountryoption();
  </script>
        {/literal}
  
{elseif $formdata.country==2}
  {literal}
        <script type="text/javascript">
        showspeccountryoption();
  </script>
        {/literal}
{else}
  {literal}
        <script type="text/javascript">
        hidecountryoption();
  </script>
        {/literal}       
 {/if}

Answer (score 0):

Please add active dives in cookies and when page load check cookie and if there is some value then make them active.